# Custom shape design for button in android

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to create a shape for Button that would have one side round and other right side slop , the actual image and a shadow.

I'm tried alot but i'm not understand how to draw it and how to draw shadow for same.

[image: I want to draw a custom shape like this]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe, you should think about using canvas? You can draw your button as a sprite, and place it on canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design the shape whatever you want in any designing tool, export it as SVG. Then, in android studio right click on "drawable" folder -> new vector asset, then choose the exported SVG file from your local disc.
Now you can able to set the created drawable as button background.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/custom-buttons-in-android-using-android-studio/) is the information about custom buttons. In a different approach you can use  [canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) and onClickListener.

Comment: [Provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)